# Bash/Python processes matching

Tags: python, linux, bash, process

I can use

```
pgrep -f 'keyword1 | keyword2'
```

to run a pgrep and return all processes that match either keyword.

How can I use & to do this instead? I just want processes that contain both keywords

The following patterns failed:

```
 pgrep -f 'keyword1 & keyword2'
 pgrep -f 'keyword2 && keyword2'
```

> MAN pgrep(1)
>
> OPTIONS
>
> -f     The pattern is normally only matched against the process
>   name.  When -f is set, the full command line is used.

.

Side question:
Is there a built in Python library for running these commands? I couldnt seem to find one and everyone suggested using subprocess.Popen(), which is how I'm running the 'pgrep' command, however I'd prefer a pure Python solution if it's available

Comment: Have you heard of the `re` module?

Comment: I have indeed. That's for regular expressions yeah? Will the bash command pick up the Python regular expression if I'm running it through subprocess.Popen('pgrep [ re ]')?

Comment: What do you want returned, a list of pids?

Comment: Maybe `pgrep keyword1.*keyword2| keyword2.*keyword1`  will work?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/590384/grep-searching-two-words-in-a-line

Comment: @Alan I don't do python but reading the output from `ps ax -o pid,cmd` line by line and do regex matching on it might be your answer.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham first part works a charm. I've removed the 2nd pattern condition as I dont need this part but the first works fine for my setup.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Remember the quotes and you are on the right track :-) `pgrep 'keyword1.*keyword2|keyword2.*keyword1'`

Comment: @andlrc.yep, quotes would be handy :)

Comment: @Alan, I was not sure if the order could be reversed, if keyword1 is always first then yep that will work fine

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'd like to accept your solution as the answer if you could add one to the question. I think based on all the replies, the pgrep -f 'k1.*k2|k2.*k1' seems the cleanest

Comment: @Alan, I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use or with a wildcard reversing the pattern to get either keyword in any order.

```
pgrep -f 'keyword1.*keyword2|keyword2.*keyword1'
```

Comment: pgrep -f for extended search

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure you can do that with `pgrep` you can however use awk:

```
ps ax -o pid,cmd | awk '{pid = $1; $1=""}/[k]eyword1/ && /keyword2/ {print pid}'
```

The reason i use `[k]eyword1` is to avoid matching the awk process.

If PCRE is supported with pgrep something like this would work:

```
pgrep -f '(?=.*keyword1)(?=.*keyword2)'
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to do a grep 'and' is to grep multiple times. Since `pgrep` returns `pids` you have to filter the list of processes directly and then extract the PID:

```
ps ax -o pid,cmd | grep 'keyword1' | grep 'keyword2' | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: Your code could be simplified to `ps aux | awk '/[k]eyword1/ && /keyword2/ {print $2}'` But will still give false positive since the columns user,pid,cpu,mem, ... also can be matched.

Comment: @andlrc I don't know `awk`, I don't plan on learning another weird shell language that I don't have much use for, and I wouldn't be surprised if others felt the same. It's just a nice way to extract a column. The multiple grep pattern is simple to understand and can be applied in situations where `awk` isn't needed at all.

Comment: It's how you look at it. I would say the grep isn't needed at all. But if you atay to your point you might consider change the awk part with `tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f2` ;)